# bash loop through two Directories

Tags: bash, quotes

I try to loop through two directories and echo all files with a given extension with this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
FOLDERS=/sdd/DATA/ /sdc/storage/
for d in $FOLDERS; do
echo "$d"
  FILES=$d*.txt
  for f in $FILES; do
    echo "$f"
  done
done
```

but I do not get this script to work!
I get bash: sdc/storage/ is a directory

Comment: I would expect you to get an error like `-bash: /sdc/storage: is a directory`

Comment: ...which can be fixed by enclosing `/sdd/DATA/ /sdc/storage/` in quotation marks. (Without, that line sets `FOLDERS=/sdd/DATA/` and then attempts to *execute* `/sdc/storage/`, which doesn't work because -- guess what -- it's a directory. ;-) ) Even better would be to be aware of filenames with spaces in them, and either doing "the IFS thing" with `for ... in ...`, or using `find ... -exec ...`.

Comment: @DevSolar, ...*could* be fixed that way, but it'd be very bad practice to define `FOLDERS` as a string rather than an array. Aiming for the most obvious issue first, it'd break the moment you had a directory name with spaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing this right would look like:

```
#!/bin/bash
folders=( /sdd/DATA/ /sdc/storage/ )
for d in "${folders[@]}"; do
  echo "$d"
  files=( "$d"*.txt )
  printf '%s\n' "${files[@]}" # print the files array, one per line
done
```

Note:

- `array=( "first item" "second item" )` defines a two-item array; `"${array[@]}"` expands to those items.
- When expanding an element, we want to quote the parts the shell *shouldn't* string-split or glob-expand, but leave any glob patterns unquoted; thus, `"$d"*.txt`.
- We're using lowercase names for user-defined variables. This is per [POSIX-defined recommendation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html), which specify all-caps names as used for variables meaningful to the operating system and shell, whereas all other names are reserved for application use.